# JMX connection between pods in Openshift

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, jmx

I'm trying to run jmx on ocp. I've set all required parameters in my container. When creating a container, I set the environment variables:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

When I try to connect to my service (using service IP or hostname) - I get connection refused:

```
IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: service.namespace-18569.svc
```

After a few attempts, I tried to check JMX endpoint using curl -I.

After checking in pod terminal (`curl -I 127.0.0.1:JMXPORT/Endpoint`) I get a response from the JMX server.

Unfortunately when I tried to use `curl -I` with service IP/Hostname (in the same pod terminal) - I get connection refused.

Is it possible to make a JMX connection between different pods using IP service?

EDIT:

My deployment config:

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2019-02-06T17:11:36Z'
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: napeOfApp
  name: napeOfApp
  namespace: nameOfMynamespace
  resourceVersion: '202879946'
  selfLink: /apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/nameOfMynamespace/deploymentconfigs/napeOfApp
  uid: 42606226-2a32-11e9-9b9a-02e3ccdc5484
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    deploymentconfig: napeOfApp
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: napeOfApp
        deploymentconfig: napeOfApp
      name: napeOfApp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: 'my image repo'
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: napeOfApp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 3084  //(JMX PORT) 
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 3104
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 7005
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 3584Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 2560Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  test: false
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2019-02-06T17:11:41Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2019-02-06T17:11:41Z'
      message: Deployment config has minimum availability.
      status: 'True'
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: '2019-02-06T17:11:42Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2019-02-06T17:11:42Z'
      message: replication controller "napeOfApp" successfully rolled out
      reason: NewReplicationControllerAvailable
      status: 'True'
      type: Progressing
  details:
    causes:
      - type: ConfigChange
    message: config change
  latestVersion: 1
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 0
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

3084 is JMX port.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a JMX connection between different pods using IP service?

Yes, it should work seamlessly, either using the service IP address or the service name according to how [DNS works in K8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

Looks like the problem for you is this:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

This is basically binding to `127.0.0.1` only and allowing only local connections. You might want to try `0.0.0.0` so that external connections are allowed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought that if in the container I run jmx on the port (127.0.0.1, port 1099) , which is exposed to the site outside (in docker and service) - my solution will work. I will check 0.0.0.0  and let you know. Thanks

Comment: unfortunately it didn`t help. Still geting: IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: service.namespace-18569.svc

Comment: Can you post your deployment or pod definition?

Comment: Can you check with `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<<IP/HostName>>` instead of 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Thanks, I`ve just added deployment config. JMX works only within pod. There is problem with connecting from another one

Comment: That's not the deployment yaml, It's one that says `kind: Deployment`

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess, if you are seeing a *connection refused* error, that the service port is wrong.  The reason is that "connection refused" itself means that the port isn't even open at all.

So, your probably just trying to access the service on the wrong IP.

This happens when, for example, you try to access a service port on a host IP.  Remember, the service port is *internal* to the cluster, whereas the host port will expose this port on a (typically 5 digit) port.

To figure out, do `oc get svc -o wide` and look at the node port that your service is bound on.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think that the service ip/hostname is correct.. I have service ip and hostname. I use hostname in my second pod (with functional tests). All other http endpoints in this service work fine - so hostname is correct. There is only jmx endpoint/port problem